# How can I match two capital letters together, that aren't preceded by special characters, using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, special-characters

I've read through a lot of really interesting stuff recently about regex.  Especially about [creating your own regex boundaries](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html)

One thing that I don't think I've seen done (I'm 100% it has been done, but I haven't noticed any examples) is how to exclude a regex match if it's preceded by a 'special character', such as & ! % $ #.  For example:

If I use the regex (Note this is from C#)

```
([A-Z]{2,}\\b)
```

It will match any capital letters that are two or more in length, and use the `\b` boundary to make sure the two capital letters don't start with or end with any other letters.  But here's where I'm not sure how this would behave:

AA **-Match**

sAB **-No Match**

ACs **-No Match**

!AD **-Match**

AF! **-Match**

I would like to know how to select only two or more capital letters that aren't preceded by a lower case letter/number/symbol, or followed by a lower case letter/number/special characters.

I've seen people use spaces, so make sure the string starts with or ends with a space, but that doesn't work if it's at the beginning or end of a line.

So, the output I would look for from the example above would be:

AA **-Match**

sAB **-No Match**

ACs **-No Match**

!AD **-No Match**

AF! **-No Match**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds kind of like you're wanting a word boundary on both Sides of the 2 upper case?

Comment: What kind of "symbol"do you mean? `\p{S}`?

Comment: symbol was probably the wrong word.  I should have said special characters like I did earlier in the question "!@#$%^&*()"

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a word boundary, on both sides that excludes letters/numbers/special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
(?<![a-z\d!@#$%^&*()])[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z\d!@#$%^&*()])
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5Ba-z%5Cd!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%5D)%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D(%3F!%5Ba-z%5Cd!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%5D)&i=AA%20-Match%0D%0AsAB%20-No%20Match%0D%0AACs%20-No%20Match%0D%0A!AD%20-Match%0D%0AAF!%20-Match)

The `(?<![a-z\d!@#$%^&*()])` lookbehind makes sure there is no lowercase letters (`[a-z]`), digits (`\d`), or special characters that you defined. If there is one, the match is failed, nothing is returned.

The `(?![a-z\d!@#$%^&*()])` lookahead also fails a match if the same characters are found after the ALLCAPS letters.

See more details on [*Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a great explanation.  I hadn't been using \d at all, and now I can explore lookbehind and lookahead more.  Thanks!

Comment: Besides `\d`, in C# you can use `\p{N}` to match digits, but `\d` is shorter. Only a side note: the `\d` will also match all Unicode digits (Arabic, Hebrew, Hindi, etc) so you might still want to limit to only ASCII ones with `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's enough to just precede the pattern you have with a negation of lower case letter and any symbols you want to exclude. My example only excludes `!`, but you can add to the list as appropriate. `^` inside brackets negates what is inside them. So, for example, you can incorporate the pattern

```
/[^a-z!][A-Z]{2,}[^a-z!]/g
```